# A question on the "usual" conditions of a probability space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, filtrations

I am reading a paper where it states the following:

"Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\{{\mathcal{F}_t}\}_{t≥0}, \mathbb{P})$ be a complete probability space with a filtration $\{{\mathcal{F}_t}\}_{t≥0}$ satisfying the usual conditions (i.e., it is increasing and right continuous while $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all $\mathbb{P}$-null sets)"

Can some explain these conditions further? What are $\mathbb{P}$-null sets?

Comment: It is a complete measure

Comment: @Andrew Can you expand?

Comment: Look up the definition of a complete mess

Comment: If OP looks that up they may come to  my profile ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The usual conditions for a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}\}_{t\geq 0}$ are that:

1. It is right-continuous: $\mathcal{F}_t = \bigcap_{s>t} \mathcal{F}_s$, and
2. $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains all the null sets of $\mathcal{F}$ (i.e. it is complete)

Condition (2) means that if $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mathbb{P}(A)=0$, then for all $B \subseteq A$ we have $\mathbb{P}(B) = 0$. Condition 1 is nice as it allows us to deal with processes with cadlag paths. Condition 2 oftentimes makes analysis a bit easier without it being too strict a condition, as any filtration can be enlarged to be complete simply by augmenting it with the subsets of sets with probability zero.

Comment: Condition 2 is slightly stronger than that: It's that $\mathcal F_0$ contains all the null sets of $\mathcal F$, not just itself.  That is, if $A \in \mathcal F$ and $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$, then for all $B \subseteq A$ we have $B \in \mathcal F_0$.

Comment: @user6247850 thanks for spotting that; updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: @JoseAvilez in your answer, what is $\mathbb{P}(B)=…$?

Comment: @Math woops, typo! Zero of course